# asp.net core 2.0 validation flash sessions

Tags: validation, asp.net-core

When the validation fails I want to redirect back with the validation errors(Laravel like).

Laravel example of redirecting with errors:

```
redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Email already exists']);
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult ProcessLogin(LoginRequest loginRequest)
{
    if (! ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Redirect back to login view and display error messages.
    }

    // Login handling....
}
```

Does asp.net core 2.0 support this natively?
All I could find was returning the errors as json or by javascript validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most typical and standard approach is the PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) pattern, which ASP.NET Core (and MVC, in general) follows. With this pattern, you redirect *on success*. If there's a validation issue, you simply return the view. In other words:

```
public IActionResult Login()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Login(LoginRequest loginRequest)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // do login
        return Redirect("/some/url");
    }

    return View(loginRequest);
}
```

The `ModelState` object (which includes the list of validation errors) is available to the view naturally, without having to pass the errors in some way from one request to the other.

Comment: I am used to redirect with a flash session that contains the errors so the view will be displayed in a `get` request. This way pressing f5 after an error won't matter. But I see that this is the asp.net core standard so I will use it.